# Encoding and post url connection -ios,

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Java Code need to write an equivalent in objectiveC.

CAn you please help me out:

**JavaCode**
    URL url;

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn;
            DataOutputStream printout;
            BufferedReader input;
            url = new URL(IDP_URL);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // Specify the content type.
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            // Send POST output.
            printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
            String content = "username="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(username, UTF_8_TYPE)
                    + "&password="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(password, UTF_8_TYPE)
                    + "&client_assertion_type="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(tokenType, UTF_8_TYPE)
                    + "&client_assertion="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(appToken, UTF_8_TYPE)
                    + "&spEntityID="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:8080/opensso",
                            UTF_8_TYPE);
            printout.writeBytes(content);
            printout.flush();
            printout.close();
            // Get response data.
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn
                    .getInputStream()));
            do {
                str = input.readLine();
            } while (str == null);
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception: ", e);
        }
```

**Equivalent ios code:**

```
- (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{

    //            NSString *result = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    //            return [result autorelease];
    return [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

-(void) IdpServiceCall {


    NSString* strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&client_assertion_type=%@&client_assertion=%@&spEntityID=%@",
     [self urlEncodeValue:strUsrName],[self urlEncodeValue:strPasswrd],[self urlEncodeValue:@"JWT"],[self urlEncodeValue:strAppTknContent],[self urlEncodeValue:@"http://localhost:8080/opensso"]];
    NSHTTPURLResponse  *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;       
    NSURL *nsurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://10.230.148.253:8080/IDP/services/login/authuser"];  
    NSMutableURLRequest*   urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:nsurl]; 
        NSData* dataRequest = [NSData dataWithBytes:[strRequest UTF8String] length:[strRequest length]];//this line is for making the nsstring to utf8string and not encoding
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody: dataRequest];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/plain"];
    [urlRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:3.0];
    [urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSUrl];    

    NSData *responseData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *result =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
        NSLog(@"downloaded idp output  %@",result);     
}
```

im not getting the desired output it 0 bytes.

Please spot me the issue.Would be greatful.

Comment: What have you tried yourself - Breakpoints and stepping through the code to examine the values stored in the variables and the return values from the function calls followed by checking the documentation for the methods called to make sure they are correct? Or did you just find it not working and posted it on here?

Comment: i did al the steps debugging step by step result im getting 0 bytes after sending the synchronous download

Comment: Use Asynchronous NSURLConnection, and place a breakpoint in didReceiveData method, didReceiveResponse method and in didFailWithError method print error to console. Check this: https://gist.github.com/1716675

Comment: And are you certain that your server is working? The URL you are addressing in the Java and Objective-C code is different

Comment: have spend twodays solving the issue trying synchronous asynchronous method debug breakpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, only the NSData for the HTTP Body looks odd.
Try to build your data more like this:

```
    appToken = [prefs objectForKey:@"Applicasa appToken"];
    [data appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",@"Key",@"Value"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [_request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Let me know if you it worked for you

Comment: thanks for the reply problem was wit encoding uncomment this piece of code worked fyn NSString *result = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

Comment: I am gald to hear that you managed it.<br>Any way, if you are dealing with converting NSString,don't work too hard, the next link might be helpful <br>https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

Comment: hey thnx alot sorry fr late reply